# what is meant by partitioning the primitive along x y z axis?

Tags: c++, nvidia, partitioning, raytracing, bounding-box

in ray tracing, while constructing BVH we use centroids of bound of primitives to partition the set of objects to subsets. there is a tachnique Surface Area Heuristics (SAH) that tells

“Which of a number of possible partitions to split a primitive will lead to the BEST acceleration structure?”

it further says that partition can be done along X,Y, Z axis so what is meant by partitioning the primitive along x y z axis?

Comment: also what is sorting of primitives along co ordinate axis?

Comment: It basically discusses using axis aligned planes. One such plane may be Z=2(every point on the plane has z=2). Space is then partitioned by this plane. All those points with Z<2 lie on one side of the plane, while all those with Z>2 lie on the other side of the plane. It's just the same for the X and Y axes too. You may consider that Euclidean space is partitioned by the 3 axis aligned planes that intersect at 0,0,0 - they cut it into 8 distinct regions.

Comment: so y are we partitioning primitives along x y z plane? what advantage does it give?

Comment: Simple - it lets you instantly discard items/objects/points that do not fit particular criteria - in this case, one of location. Imagine using a z=0 partitioning plane. If you were to view the scene from the origin, looking down the z-axis in either direction, you could instantly discard all of the objects that lie on a particular side of the plane. So, by extension, if you partition the space that holds your objects - then you only need to test some of them when checking for intersecting rays - only the ones that are in the appropriate partition of space. The others can be discarded instantly